# Can the object of a class having a constructor be created?

Tags: java

Given this class:

```
public class MyClassOne {

private World world;
  

  public MyClassOne(World world) { 
    this.world = world;
  }

public void myMethod() {
    //do something;
  }
}
```

I tried creating an object `MyClassOne` in `MyClassTwo`:

```
Public class MyClassTwo{
  
MyClassOne mco = new MyClassOne();  // error thrown on this line

public void myMethod2() {
    //do something
   
  }
}
```

I gpt a compilation eror:

```
'MyClassOne(config.World)' in 'mypackage.MyClassOne' cannot be applied to '()
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I successfully create an object of `MyClassOne` given it contains a constructor?

Comment: Your constructor has a ***parameter***, so you need to supply it.  Alternatively you can create a no-parameter constructor.

Comment: @PM 77, I supplied it but the compiler says `Value 'world' is always 'null' `

Comment: You need to have/create an ***instance*** of `World` and pass it to your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a `World` reference to the constructor to create a `MyClassOne`. That's what your constructor is declared to need.

Comment: `MyClassOne mco = new MyClassOne(World)` throws a compiler error `Expression expected` with `World` underlined in red

Comment: World is a class. You need an instance of that class. Something like World w = new World(); and pass w to the constructor.